# Count number of articles in categories

Tags: php, sql, mysql

This code only shows categories with articles in them.
I want to show all categories.
Pls help.

```
$query = "SELECT C.id, C.jcat_name,COUNT(A.catid) AS catid FROM jt_categories C INNER JOIN jt_articles A ON C.id = A.catid GROUP BY C.id";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to [left join](http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/mysql-left-join-and-right-join.php)

```
 SELECT C.id, C.jcat_name,COUNT(A.catid) AS catid FROM jt_categories C 
LEFT JOIN jt_articles A ON C.id = A.catid GROUP BY C.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Change INNER JOIN for LEFT JOIN in your query.

INNER JOIN looks explicitely for the join in the data

Answer (score 1):

replace the inner join by a left outer join

Answer (score 1):

Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try LEFT JOIN ? bc. (i think) in second table u have NULL articles for some categories.